# Python shebang line with Python3

Tags: linux, python-3.x, shebang

I have the following python file:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/my_app$ cat version_py3.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print "Python 2 print statement"
```

and I thought **python version_py3.py** will enforce the use of python3. But the code ran fine. and **python3 version_py3.py** gives expected error.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/my_app$ python3 version_py3.py
  File "version_py3.py", line 3
    print "Python 2 print statement"
                               ^
```

Also, there is no /usr/bin/env folder on my linux. Am I missing something here with the shebang right, but Python 2 and Python 3 are both installed on my computer.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/my_app$ python -V
Python 2.7.6
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/my_app$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.3
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/my_app$
```

Comment: hm, what does `env python3` run? `env` is just another shell command, no folder present.

Comment: How did you run the script in the first experiment? `./version_py3.py`? `/usr/bin/env` is a program that will lookup `python3` on the PATH. Its part of a base ubuntu install and if its not there, something is seriously wrong. Trying to run the program as `./version_py3.py` with missing `env` should result in an error. Something like "bad interpreter". And the python should not run.

Comment: OP won't tell us how he ran the program which makes speculating about the problem pointless. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute a script and you want have the shebang line respected, you may not prepend "python" in the command. A binary executable as the head of a command, which could work in she-bang as well, any given she-bang is ignored because the command executable is always preferred by the kernel.

Example: So let's assume you have a little python script, but with cat in the shebang. What happens when you set the executable bit of the script and call it as the command head is that the system first reads the first line, strips off the initial two bytes and tries to execute the (mandatorily binary) executable and feed it the script file.

```
$ /tmp/getver
#!/bin/cat
import sys
print( sys.version )
```

And now try and see yourself prepending `python`, `python2` and/or `python3`.

Trivia: The interpreter **may** choose to process the shebang another time, on its own. E.g. `perl` used to respect any flags like `-w` given, whether it is given on the shebang or on the command, no matter if `perl` is the command head.

Answer (score 1):

Try to located the python installation with `locate` for example, and set it in your shebang, like `#!/usr/bin/python3.6` . I bet it's here.

Comment: 1) On linux you type "which python3" to locate the binary. 2) That's not the cross-platform way of doing this. Your code should be usable in any OS, hence he asks for the usr/bin/env.

Comment: `command -v python3` should be cross-platform. sh-based shells, not cmd.exe ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found the solution. In python3, the syntax for print is different. The message has to be inside the parenthesis.

Try `print("Python 2 print statement")`